# How to use Option[T] to handle null value well in scala?

Tags: scala

Java code:

```
public static Connection connection = null;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if(connection == null){
        connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf);
    }
    //using connection object to do something
}
```

converting to Scala code:

someone tell me use `Option[T]` to handle `null` value, but I don't how to use `Option[T]` well, I think it very troublesome.

Scala code:

```
    var connOpt: Option[Connection] = None
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        //check `connOpt` Option
        connOpt match {
            case Some(connection) => { /* using `connection` to do something-----code1  */    }
            case _ => {
                val connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection()
                connOpt = Option(connection)
                // using `connection` to do something------code2
                }   
        }
    }
```

you can see scala code.

1. I need check `connOpt` always when I need use `connOpt`.
2. *code1* and *code2* is the same code, I need write two times, I know I can use function to package code1 or code2, but it's very troublesome.

How to handle this case?

Comment: How can `connection` ever be not `null` at the top of the `main` method? Why do you need that `if` at all?

Comment: Maybe you want to look at `lazy val` to get initialization on first use?

Comment: Take a look at http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/12/19/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-5-the-option-type.html

Comment: @Thilo if I use `lazy val`, how to close `connection`?

Comment: @Guo if you use `lazy val` you can call `close()` on the Connection just like you always would. You can't reset the `val` to null, as you might have in java, but it will just be a reference to a close()ed Connection, it's network/DBMS resources will have been cleaned up. that said, storing a Connection as a member variable is generally a bad idea, in Scala or in Java. store a `DataSource` backed by a Connection pool instead, and acquire/`close()` your Connections on an as-needed basis.

Comment: @SteveWaldman  Thanks, I got it!

Comment: And also you Scala code can be better expressed with `val connection = connOpt getOrElse ConnectionFactory.createConnection()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use the 'fold' method to do what you want like this

```
var connOpt:Option[Connection] = None
def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val connection = connOpt.fold(ConnectionFactory.createConnection()){conn => conn}
    //using connection object to do something
}
```

The logic of code mentioned above is the same as your java code that does not write the 'code1' and 'code2' two times.

Using the following example to explain the usage of 'fold'

```
obj.fold{/*the obj is null, you can return the value you want*/}{a => a
/*if the obj is Some(value), the 'a' is just the 'value'*/
}
```

Good luck with you

Comment: @Guo, @Jerry: this solution works but it's not idiomatic Scala. You shouldn't use a `var` unless it's warranted from a pragmatic/efficiency perspective; this is not such case. `fold` is also not meant to be used that way: you're using the `zero` block to perform a side-effect that also you are not error-handling; what if it fails? `connOpt` always starts as `None` and `main` is always the first invoked `def`; therefore the second code block is unreachable code. With `connOpt` being a `var`, you are at risk of sharing mutable state; will be hard to test this code. Please consider my solution.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your business logic; not so much on the programming language.

**Does it make sense to keep your component alive if the connection attempt is unsuccessful?**

You might want to "fail early": if you can't connect, either throw an Exception or stop your component. In this case, using `Option` is an unnecessary abstraction.

**If your component should survive if it fails to connect, you could do this:**

```
val maybeConn: Option[Connection] = Option(ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf))

maybeConn foreach doConnRelatedOperation

doOtherOperationThatDoesNotRequireConn

def doConnRelatedOperation(conn: Connection) = println(conn)
def doOtherOperationThatDoesNotRequireConn = "hello!"
```

**In this code example:**

- `Option(ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf))` will return either `Some(conn)` or `None` (I'm assuming `createConnection` doesn't throw; if it could then maybe you want to use the `Try` functor instead)
- `maybeConn foreach doConnRelatedOperation` will either do nothing if `maybeConn` is `None` or invoke the side-effecting function `doConnRelatedOperation` that takes a `Connection` as an argument if `maybeConn` is `Some(conn)`.
- Note that, in this example, `doOtherOperationThatDoesNotRequireConn` will execute even if there is no connection.

**Finally**

Let's say your `createConnection` function might throw an `Exception`. In that case, `Option` is the wrong abstraction. In that case, you may want to do `lazy val maybeConn: Try[Connection] = Try(ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf))` instead (basically `Try` instead of `Option`).

Note the beautifulness in that the rest of the code doesn't need to be modified! The `doConnRelatedOperation` function will only be executed if the connection was created, and the `doOtherOperationThatDoesNotRequireConn` will be executed after, irrespective of having the connection or not. The exception will not affect your code flow!

Welcome to Scala's Good Parts :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `Option` instead of null is only one of the things "they say" about scala. Your problem is that you chose to use that one (fairly random) piece of advice, and ignore all the others.

The other piece of advice, more relevant in this case is: avoid using state and mutable vars. You can safely throw out both "code 1" and "code 2", and just do this:

```
lazy val = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val connOpt: Option[Connection] = None
def main(args: Array[String]) {
    //check `connOpt` Option
    connOpt.orElse(Some(ConnectionFactory.createConnection()).map { 
        connection =>
        // code 1
    }
}
```